# multipleSelect jQuery não atualiza os valores recebidos em JSON dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alguém poderia me explicar porque a classe *multipleSelect()* do *jQuery* não atualiza os valores recebidos via *JSON*?

Por exemplo, quando eu seleciono um estado, no meu outro campo de seleção, são filtradas as cidades relacionadas daquele estado. Quando eu *linko* o *jQuery* no campo das cidades, o campo só fica em branco, ou seja, ele só recebe o valor de quando é carregado a página, que no caso é em branco.

**Quero saber como eu recupero o estado e jogo as cidades filtradas dinâmicamente, e onde faço a ligação ao meu campo cidades?**

```
$('select[name=uf]').on('change', function () {
    var uf = $(this).val();
    $.get('/judicial/get-cidades/' + uf, function (busca) {
        $('select[id=comarca_id]').empty();
            $('select[id=comarca_id]').append('<option value=""> </option>');
        $.each(busca, function (key, value) {
            $('select[id=comarca_id]').append('<option value=' + value.name + '>' + value.name + '</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name=comarca_id]').multiselect({
        numberDisplayed: 0,
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        allSelectedText: 'Todos',
        nonSelectedText: 'Selecione',
        nSelectedText: 'Selecionado',
        selectAllText: 'Todos',
    });
});
```

[Aqui](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) é o link de onde peguei esse *jQuery*.

Comment: Posta o código pro pessoal dar uma olhada...

Comment: Coloquei o js onde faço a ligação do jquery ao campo das cidades

Comment: Já tentou rodar o  $('select[name=comarca_id]').multiselect({... novamente depois que terminar de preencher o select?

Comment: Primeiro eu jogo as cidades filtradas pelo estado no select e depois eu executo o multiselect(). Coloquei no na minha pergunta agora como eu jogo os dados no select tbm..

Answer (score 1):

"Resolvi o problema". Resolvi o problema deixando de um jeito que eu possa utilizar na produção.

```
$('select[name=uf]').on('change', function () { // ativa quando selecionar uma UF
  $('select[name=comarca_id]').multiselect('destroy'); // destroy o multiple select existente
  var uf = $(this).val();
  $.get('/judicial/get-cidades/' + uf, function (busca) { // buscando as cidades pela rota get-cidades + uf
      $('select[id=comarca_id]').empty(); // esvaziando os options das comarcas
      $.each(busca, function (key, value) {
          $('select[id=comarca_id]').append('<option value=' + value.name + '>' + value.name + '</option>'); // inserindo os options com as cidades
      });
    $('select[name=comarca_id]').multiselect(); // ativando o multiselect no campo após fazer todo o carregamento das cidades
  });  });
```